# How can I enable WPF DataGrid validation of a collection of complex objects on property changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

I have a ViewModel class that encapsulates an ObservableCollection of complex objects. I want to display these in a WPF DataGrid, one object per row, mapping object fields to columns.

For data validation, I want to check changes to one row against the properties of other rows, for example to check for unique values.

I have written a ValidationRule and added it to a BindingGroup on the DataGrid, but it is not called when items are edited. Why not? The rule is called when the grid is initialised.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridValidationTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridValidationTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CBItems}"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image
                                       Source="/DataGridValidationTest;component/error.png"
                                       ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={
                                             RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                             AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                                             Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                                       Margin="0"
                                       Width="11" Height="11" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup ValidatesOnNotifyDataError="True" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                        <local:DuplicateValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
                    </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                </BindingGroup>
            </DataGrid.BindingGroup>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header ="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace DataGridValidationTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel vm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            vm = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
            InitializeComponent();
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "a", Value = 0 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "b", Value = 1 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "c", Value = 2 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "d", Value = 3 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "e", Value = 4 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "f", Value = 5 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "g", Value = 6 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "h", Value = 7 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "i", Value = 8 });
            vm.CBItems.Add(new ItemType { Id = "j", Value = 9 });
        }
    }
    public class DuplicateValidationRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var bg = value as BindingGroup;
            if (bg == null)
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);

            var dg = bg.Owner as DataGrid;
            if (dg == null)
                return new ValidationResult(true, null);

            HashSet<string> usedValues = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (var item in dg.Items)
            {
                var itemValue = item as ItemType;
                string ev = itemValue?.Value.ToString();
                if (ev != null)
                {
                    if (usedValues.Contains(ev))
                    {
                        return new ValidationResult(false, "Values must be unique.");
                    }
                    usedValues.Add(ev);
                }
            }
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

View model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DataGridValidationTest
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        private ObservableCollection<ItemType> cBItems = new ObservableCollection<ItemType>();
        public ObservableCollection<ItemType> CBItems
        {
            get => cBItems;
            set => cBItems = value;
        }
    }

    public class ItemType : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string id = "";
        public string Id
        {
            get => id;
            set
            {
                id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
        private int _value = 0;
        public int Value
        {
            get => _value;
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Value");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to add the validationRule to the Column itself?

Comment: The `DataGrid` has a `RowValidationRules` property that should be used to validate multiple values. Please refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control) for more information.